# Alluvial diagram with within-group-associations in R

Tags: python, r, visualization, graph-visualization

I have a question about visualizing the alluvial diagram in R.

My goal is to show the association between multiple groups so I decided to use an alluvial diagram. However, an alluvial diagram usually shows the association through the source, target1, target2...Could I ask if there is a visualization tool that can add flows within source/target1/target2? like:

[image: example diagram screenshot]

Other than the alluvial diagram, are there any other visualization charts that can be used for a similar performance?
Thanks so much, any reply would be greatly appreciated!

I have checked some of the existing package in R, but no one has the function to visualize association within source/target.